# How to transform React material ui makestyles to emotion

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I want to make a resizable drawer and I found this code:
https://codesandbox.io/s/34ife?file=/src/CustomDrawer.js:0-2307

I know current Material UI 5 no longer supports makestyles and I want to convert this code to use material UI 5 emotion style.

I have looked up some articles but still feel so complicated for conversion.

Can anyone provide some examples of how to convert this resizable drawer code to material UI 5 style?
Thank you.